# ADB No Devices Found / Tablet restart

Tags: android, adb

I have andoroid tablet which starts only to boot screen. No combination of power and vol +/- leads to recovery. Tablet is responsible when connected to PC. So I would like to try reset is via ADB.

When I connect tablet to PC, it apears for few second in device manager. I was able to install driver and now it apears as MediaTek PreLoader USB VCom. But unfortunately only for few seconds.

So when I run ADB.exe devices - list of attached devices is empty. adb server is running.

Any tips what to try please?
Thank you

Comment: check the cable, change usb port, try another device with the same cable, restart adb, restart the computer. What is the type of the tablet you have?

Comment: Thank you very much. Some progress... With different cable the device is no longer preloader, but MediaTek USB port (Com9), but adb devices still do not see anything :( Tablet is Prestigio multipad 4 Ultra Quad 8.0 3G

Comment: You're most welcome, maybe this can help http://www.hardreset.info/devices/prestigio/prestigio-multipad-4-ultra-quad-80-3g/

Comment: Thank you. I saw this before, unfortunately none of these methods works...

Comment: Sorry to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have the appropriate adb driver installed for your tablet.

Also, I recommend using [Universal ADB Driver](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/). It works for pretty much any android device.

**However**, you must have ADB options enabled beforehand on your tablet (before it went unresponsive). Otherwise, ADB will not be of any use to you.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am affraid that adb was not enabled... So I think I am done...